# Cannot run gradle commands terminal

Tags: gradle

I am having an issue with gradle in my Android Studio project. Whenever i run any tasks on the command line: clean,assemble etc the only task that gets run is build. I am using the latest version of android studio. I also have a gradlew executable file. The same thing happens when i attempt to run tasks using that. I have tried re-installing gradle locally on my machine but the issue keeps persisting. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
operating system = Ubuntu 13.04
```

gradle -v

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08)
OS:           Linux 3.8.0-35-generic amd64
```

examples commands i am executing are 'gradle clean' 'gradle check' 'gradle compileLint' 'gradle compileLint'

I have also tried using the gradle wrapper './gradlew clean' etc

I am using openJdk as my java platform.

Comment: Please provide more details, such as a minimal build script that produces this behavior, the exact command you run, its exact output, output of `gradlew -v`, etc.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I updated my question there with some more information. i can run gradle with a nonsense command after it and i still get the same result. I must be doing something completely wrong..

Comment: Please provide the exact output when running a command, and a minimal build script that produces the behavior. Also, double-check that you are running the command from the directory that contains the build script. Also check if running with `--info` or `--debug` provides any clues.

Comment: BTW: your Gradle uses Oracle's JDK and not OpenJDK as you claim.